# Excel concatenation of one column based on values in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, concatenation

Similar to this: [Excel - pivot values in one cell (as comma-separated value)](https://superuser.com/questions/249437/excel-pivot-values-in-one-cell-as-comma-separated-value)

Except it can be a VBA solution, and I do not have duplicates in Column A. Instead, there are blank rows below each value:

```
Name1|Fact1
------|Fact2
------|Fact3
------|Fact4
Name2|Fact1
------|Fact2
Name3|Fact1
```

Like in the question I cite, I would like to achieve:

```
Name1|Fact1, Fact2, Fact3, Fact4
Name2|Fact1, Fact2
Name3|Fact1
```

The number of facts for each name is not uniform, so a simple formula dragged down would not work.

All values are strings.

I would prefer to use a macro to solve this, rather than the solution given in the question I cite.

Comment: @Raystafarian Sorry for not replying before - did not want to think about work over weekend. Am a complete beginner in macro design and did not even know where to start. Not that I am opposed to learning, but did not have very long to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that "The number of facts for each name is not uniform, so a simple formula dragged down would not work."

However, what you can do to insert a formula into all those blank cells is this:

1. In cell A2, insert the formula =A1
2. Copy the formula in cell A2
3. Select the entire range in cells A1:B7.
4. Hit CTRL+G.
5. Choose "special".
6. Choose "blanks"; "OK".
7. Hit CTRL+V to paste the formulas in the selected blank cells.
8. You could now copy-paste special - values to remove the formulas.

You could then proceed with the method shown in your link above.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    start:
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i + 1, 1) = "" And Cells(i + 1, 2) <> "" Then
        s = Cells(i, 2).Value & "," & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 2) = s
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo start
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing appears to happen when I run this. Macros are enabled so it should do something?

Comment: @OfficeLackey make sure you're executing it on the sheet that you're working on. Also make sure it's a module in the correct workbook.